# BOM dependency vs Parent Dependancy in Maven

Tags: maven, parent-pom, maven-bom

I would like to know the difference between Parent and BOM in pom. It looks like both solves the same problem where you do not want to include version in each individual project, but maintain it in a central (parent / BOM) maven.

Can anyone help me understand? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have one parent, but you can import multiple BOMs into your Maven project.

Also, importing a BOM will only import the dependencyManagement, while having a parent will import everything you have in that pom.

This is specially useful when you want to provide a set of default configurations for When you set the parent, you inherit all the plugin versions (and configurations) done in those plugins.

Comment: Thank you for the response.. @Pablo.. Can we have BOMs inside the parent POM too?

Comment: A parent does not import everything. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance A BOM will not import the dependencies it will import the dependencyManagement part ...